# read a file from runner in github actions using java

Tags: java, github-actions

I have couple of files: `asdf.json` and `qwer.json` that are sitting in `/runner` of self-hosted vm after github actions is run

Now I want to read those files into my java code with something like `File file = new File("asdf.json");`

I always end up getting file not found exception while doing this. I tried with `new File("runner/asdf.json")` and is still the same

Answer (score 0):

If you file is located in your repository you have to use `GITHUB_WORKSPACE` variable to access it, like this:

`${{ env.GITHUB_WORKSPACE }}/asdf.json`

and pass it to your Java code.

Of course you have checkout your repository first:

`- uses: actions/checkout@v2`